# Edit text fields in android not listed

Tags: android, android-layout

Below is my `xml` file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
    android:hint="Username" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"

    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/login_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:text="@string/login_title" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

with this `xml` only the first item is getting displayed. If I change the order, the first item in the `layout` is displayed.I need to display all the three items. I was trying to create a login page

Comment: It shouldn't be so. What device do you test on? Maybe try substituting the `LinearLayout` with `ScrollView` and see if the other views just fall off the screen? Also try reducing the `marginTop`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with this code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:hint="Username" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
            android:text="login_title" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks.. It is working. my idea of using margintop was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

replace `wrap_content` to `fill_parent`

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

and your `marginTop` is too high. I suggest to lower this value.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the margin values. And see if more than one view appears. Maybe some of the views fall out of the screen? The values for the margins are quite big.

Answer (score 0):

In you code, margins that you have provided is too large and they are going off the screen.

Try to apply small amount of margin

Here is My code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
android:id="@+id/username"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
android:hint="Username" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/password"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

android:hint="Password"
android:inputType="textPassword" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/login_title"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:text="login" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here, main thing to note is that as you are using linear Layout with vertical orientation, values of marginTop is considered from the previous control not from the top of the window,

As you are specifying

```
android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
```

for the password field, it is going off to the visible area of screen(that is 300dp from username edittext).

This is the issue with your code